# AHK write characters automatically and set cursor between these 2 characters

Tags: autohotkey

I installed ahk yesterday so I don't know very much how to use it. I want to create a script that writes characters. exemple:

I press < and it automatically puts > at the end and sets the cursor between < and >

I searched for about 30 minutes how to do this, but none of the answers were working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hotstring version (recommended):

```
:*?:<::<>{Left}
```

Hotkey version:

```
~<::Send >{Left}
```

or

```
$<::Send <>{Left}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with remapping `<` to

```
<::Send {<}{>}{Left}
```

When you type `<`, you will be typing `<`, `>`, then press the left arrow key.

Comment: when  i press< it delete it and replace it by >.

Comment: You forgot to add $ at the beginning

Comment: Use `:B0*:<::>{left}` instead.